# Amazon fire tv app design

Tags: javascript, css, html, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to develop a **side by side**  3D application for amazon fire tv using [HTML5](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/getting-started-with-web-apps-for-fire-tv),I created and loaded on my fire tv stick using [web app tester](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/tester.html)

Here is my code,

```css
#right{
 width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
height: 100%;
background-color: gray;

position: absolute;
 }
 #left{
  width:50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: gray;
 }
.container{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;

position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div id="left">
     This text shuld view as single when i enable 3D mode on my TV
     </div>
  
 <div id="right">
   This text shuld view as single when i enable 3D mode on my TV
    </div>
  
</div>
```

But this does not work,the text not shows in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

This text shuld view as single when i enable 3D mode on my TV
     
  
 
   This text shuld view as single when i enable 3D mode on my TV
    
  
This phase of code have potential to solve various issues related to installation of app,restart and update etc you can get more you may visit at [Amazon app][1] 
 like android.os.Build.MODEL

```
AFTB (Fire TV Gen 1)
AFTS (Fire TV Gen 2)
AFTM (Fire TV Stick Gen 1)
AFTT (Fire TV Stick Gen 2)
```